# Is my understanding of this conditional "value || value" assignment correct?

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I have this snippet in my script:

```js
(window.WORLD_CLOCK || (window.WORLD_CLOCK = WORLD_CLOCK))();
```

**Note**: There's a function called `WORLD_CLOCK` that's defined before this line.

From what I understand this checks to see if the `window` object contains a key called `WORLD_CLOCK`. If it does (`true`) it returns that function, if it doesn't (`false`) it assigns `WORLD_CLOCK` to window and returns the `WORLD_CLOCK` function from that assignment.

The outer parenthesis captures this function and the third (empty) pair of parenthesis calls this function.

Am I correct?

If I am, could I replace that with the following:

```js
if (typeof WORLD_CLOCK === "function") {
  if (!window.hasOwnProperty("WORLD_CLOCK")) {
    window.WORLD_CLOCK = WORLD_CLOCK;
  }
  window.WORLD_CLOCK();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: That code is rather common....

Comment: @epascarello Do you have any examples I could take a look at?

Comment: typically people write it as `window.WORLD_CLOCK = window.WORLD_CLOCK || WORLD_CLOCK`, it is all based on what the style guide you pick allows. If you do not like it, then put it in the style guide to not do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the code your colleague assumes that there is always a WORLD_CLOCK function and the steps are:

1. if `window` does not have the property WORLD_CLOCK assign the WORLD_CLOCK function to the property with the same name
2. call the property WORLD_CLOCK from the `window` object

so, maybe the rewrite could be like this:

```
if (!window.hasOwnProperty("WORLD_CLOCK") {
  window.WORLD_CLOCK = WORLD_CLOCK
}

window.WORLD_CLOCK()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be more like (not that you would accomplish it this way just a more direct translation).

```
if (window.WORLD_CLOCK) {
  window.WORLD_CLOCK();
} else {
  window.WORLD_CLOCK = WORLD_CLOCK;
  window.WORLD_CLOCK();
}
```